# JS prototype: uncaught typeerror undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having troubles trying to create a Factory in AngularJS. I just move the code in the controller to the factory and make a few changes for that to work.

This is the error that I'm having:

"El objeto no acepta la propiedad o el método 'addPoint'" (in IE)
("Object does not support property or method 'addPoint'")

"Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" (in Chrome)

This is my code:

```
function Shape (shape) {
  this.ToolName   = shape.tool;
  this.LineColor  = shape.lineColor;
  this.LineWidth  = shape.lineWidth;
  this.LineCap    = shape.lineCap;
  this.FillStyle  = shape.fillStyle;
  this.isFilled   = shape.filled;
  this.isStroked  = shape.stroked;
  this.Points     = [];
}

Shape.prototype.addPoint = function(point){
  if(this.ToolName!=='pencil' && this.Points.length>1){
    this.Points.pop();
  }
  this.Points.push(point);
};
```

This used to work when it was inside the Controller, but now Inside the factory it doesn't.

Thank you.

EDIT:

I'm sorry I didn't share more of the code. You have the source code here: https://github.com/michaeljota/Arheados/blob/master/app/scripts/controllers/main.js

That is the code of the controller. What I want to do is convert everything that is not handle by $scope into a Factory. Some one suggest a Service, but I quite don't understand well how Services works.

Thanks you again!

Comment: You may want to read upon factory. factory does not new up the provided class, you are responsible for creating the instance when using a factory. How about using a service? Please share more code.

Comment: Is this all of the code? It doesn't look like this would show that error.

Comment: I add the GitHub code to the controller. Thanks you both.

Comment: Oh! I know what you mean. So sorry. I'll edit this when I get home with the factory head.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Evan Knowles, reading my code I just find the error.

I wasn't giving the shape to the constructor, just `tmpShape = shape;` (witch is the $scope model). So I just fix it to this `tmpShape = new Shape(shape);` and it works again.

I'm really sorry for such a noob question.

Thanks you all!